# use threads for cublas calls from kernel?

Tags: cuda, cublas

BEFORE reading below! :

As I have understand , when you call cublas from the kernel :

> cublas calls are kernels themselves
>
> the threads and blocks are managed from the cublas calls
>
> a cublas call is launched by 1 thread ( and 1 block ) and then it is
>   checking the number of elements and shedules threads/blocks
>   automatically. So , you don't specify number of threads/blocks when
>   you run a cublas call.

I am launching a kernel with 1 thread and 1 block as I said above.

```
__global__ void (...)
{

    ...
    cublasCtrsm( CublasHandle , CUBLAS_SIDE_LEFT ,CUBLAS_FILL_MODE_LOWER , CUBLAS_OP_N , CUBLAS_DIAG_NON_UNIT , M , N , &alpha , inCov, M  ,  inSample, M )

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )

        cublasCdotc( CublasHandle , M , inCoil + i * M  , 1 , inSample + i * M  , 1 , devImage + i );

}
```

Now, this code works fine ( I am taking an image ) but the for loop takes too much time.I want to optimize this for loop.

So , I tried:

```
int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

if ( i < N ) 
    cublasCdotc( CublasHandle , M , inCoil + i * M  , 1 , inSample + i * M  , 1 , devImage + i );
```

But , as I said I am calling the kernel with 1 thread and 1 block.

So , is going to be executed by 1 thread only,right? 
(that's why I am not taking the image I want ,but only 1 pixel)

And this has as a concequence the expressions  `i * M` not to be evaluated for all N.

My question is how to accomplish what I want?

Comment: You have managed to complete avoid describing what it is you are trying to achieve. I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect to this as it is written.

Comment: @talonmies:I tried to edit my answer.I just want to optimize the for loop.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:What do you suggest for making the cublasCdotc run for  "N" times?

Comment: Since you are using only 1 thread/1 block, why don't you call the cublas functions from host? You may wish considering using streams if the computations are independent and your hardware permits a benefit.

Comment: @JackOLantern:I have to take the result first from the 1st cublas call (inSample) and then call the cublasCdotc , so i can't use streams.But if I call it from host as you say ,I will have again the same exactly problem , since a cublas call its a kernel itself.

Comment: If your code is not working to your satisfaction, provide a [complete MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as SO expects.  Then it's likely that someone can sort it out for you.  Note that this is not asking for *your whole code* but rather a simplified example that is complete, compilable, and demonstrates the error.

Comment: What does prevent you using the streams after you have collected inSample. Also, as @talonmies suggested, providing more details on your algorithm (what do you like to achieve) would be helpful to devise different approaches.

Comment: @JackOLantern:I will try to use streams for this call but I am not sure again how to do the "i * M" offset and I f I have to use " if ( i < N)" inside the kernel..

Comment: @Robert Crovella:The problem is that it depends from too much information and I can't create for example the data because they are arranged in a special manner ( and i am not too experienced anyway to be able to do this ),sorry.

Comment: Unless your CUDA device is of compute capability 3.5 or higher, you cannot call a kernel in another kernel. We call it nested kernels or dynamic parallelism.  In order to concurrently run kernels, as other people said, you should use CUDA stream. If you ask how, I would say "Surf and study!" In my opinion, CUDA is one of the easiest subjects you can learn from internet.

Comment: @Tae-Sung Shin:I am using a 3.5 device , so I know that I can call it like this , ok??I am not just asking how , I have a certain problem,anyway

Comment: In that case, you are not asking a proper question with enough background information for people who are willing to answer your question for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might understood the answer or want to find out , anyway...

I came with this solution.

In a global function:

```
int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    devImage[ i ] = 0;

    if ( i < N )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        {
             devImage[ i ] +=   inCoil[  i * M + j ] * inSample[  i * M + j ] - inCoil[  i * M + j ] \
                    * inSample[  i * M + j ] + inCoil[  i * M + j ] *  inSample[  i * M + j ] + inCoil[  i * M + j ] \
                    * inSample[  i * M + j ];

        }
    }
```

I did a small loop ( j < M ) instead of a big one ( M is much smaller than N).

Now , I can't think a way of using cublasCdotc running fast.